# Speech recognition in real-time with punctuation

Tags: android, speech-recognition

What is the way to implement speech recognition (voice to text) with auto punctuation? I want to use it to turn a lecture (45 min talk) into text and if possible update the view dynamically.

I tried SpeechRecognizer but it only gives me words without punctuation and stops listening after the first words.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Punctuator](https://github.com/ottokart/punctuator2), it assigns punctuation to ASR result with the help of a deep neural network.

Comment: Thank you for the example! This looks promising. I will definitely try it and compare it to the approach I use now which is ending the sentence when I restart the SpeechRecognizer.